# Why is ModelBuilder not outputting Make Feature Layer results?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

[image: Model Builder model]

This model is giving me some trouble. When I run it the is not input  into the map and when I do add the data in it is not clipped to the boundary. Any ideas? I have add model to map check in geoprocessing options.

Comment: make feature layer.... by definition a layer is a temp file. Why don't you try creating a shapefile instead.

Answer (score 2):

Feature Layers are temporary. Your data currently will only exist for the duration of the model. Per ESRI documentation of [Make Feature Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006p000000):

> **Make Feature Layer (Data Management):**
>
> Creates a feature layer from an input feature class or layer file. The
> layer that is created by the tool is temporary and will not persist
> after the session ends unless the layer is saved to disk or the map
> document is saved.

You need to write your output to disk. You can do this by running the [Feature Class to Feature Class](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000020000000) geoprocessing tool and choosing a location on disk as the output. Insert this just before your clip operation and your output should emerge.